# RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (100) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, pytorch

I already saw many people with this same error. I tried adding some lines about my CUDA and gpu and cpu at the virtual environment (that I created) python file, but any answer that I saw could help me

I am trying to install this Python tool, but I am having a problem when I am executing this software.

https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning

I have the CUDA at 10.2, Pytorch is at the last version for CUDA 10.2, and I have Python at 3.7

When I click at a button to **use vocoder at pretrained**, I got this lines **before** the **error**:

```
Building Wave-RNN
Trainable Parameters: 4.481M
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\DeepVoiceFiles\Real-Time-Voice-Cloning-master\toolbox\__init__.py", line 187, in vocode
    self.init_vocoder()
  File "C:\Program Files\DeepVoiceFiles\Real-Time-Voice-Cloning-master\toolbox\__init__.py", line 249, in init_vocoder
    vocoder.load_model(model_fpath)
  File "C:\Program Files\DeepVoiceFiles\Real-Time-Voice-Cloning-master\vocoder\inference.py", line 25, in load_model
    mode=hp.voc_mode
  File "E:\PROGRAMAS\Anaconda\envs\[Test_voice]\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 304, in cuda
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "E:\PROGRAMAS\Anaconda\envs\[Test_voice]\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 201, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "E:\PROGRAMAS\Anaconda\envs\[Test_voice]\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 201, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "E:\PROGRAMAS\Anaconda\envs\[Test_voice]\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 201, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "E:\PROGRAMAS\Anaconda\envs\[Test_voice]\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 223, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "E:\PROGRAMAS\Anaconda\envs\[Test_voice]\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 304, in <lambda>
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "E:\PROGRAMAS\Anaconda\envs\[Test_voice]\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 199, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (100) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at ..\aten\src\THC\THCGeneral.cpp:50
```

Please, someone, help me, I don't understand much about Python, CUDA and virtual environment.

I installed this following a YouTube video.

Comment: What is your graphics card? See my comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987997) to check if it's compatible with CUDA 10.2.

Comment: My graphic card is the NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M

Comment: Now I change my CUDA version to 8.0, an I change my Pytorch to cuda 8.0. But now I got a new error when I execute the file.


`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.`

Comment: I'm not nearly as familiar with tensorflow as I am with pytorch, but that error seems to indicate that tensorflow isn't installed properly.