# ValueError: Unknown CUDA arch (8.6) or GPU not supported

Tags: cuda, pytorch, gpu, ubuntu-20.04

when I build DCNv2 in my conda environment,I got this message.

I have checked cuda by nvidia-smi:

```
Tue Apr  6 20:03:13 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.67       Driver Version: 460.67       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   45C    P8    17W / 220W |    448MiB /  7979MiB |     23%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       955      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 53MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1555      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                210MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1690      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               61MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3564      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files      108MiB |
```

and nvcc -V:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Any help?

Comment: CUDA 10.1 has no support for your GPU

Answer (score 5):

Your GPU is "too new" for CUDA 10. Support for cards with [compute capability 8.6](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported) like yours was [added in CUDA 11.1](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.1.0/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#cuda-general-new-features) (thank you @RobertCrovella for the correction). This means you'll need to use CUDA 11.1 or newer.

Comment: I upgraded my CUDA to 11.3.1 and still get the same error message about "CUDA arch (8.6)". Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: @JoshBone Assuming this is related to pytorch keep in mind that pytorch does *not* use your system's cuda. It installs it's own version along with the pytorch binaries. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61034368/2790047) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62361395/2790047) for more details on how to get pytorch working with CUDA.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit `cpp_extension.py`, eg `"/usr/local/conda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py"`, and add 8.6 to the list.