# Using CUDA 11.x but getting error: Unknown CUDA arch (8.6) or GPU not supported

Tags: pytorch, cuda, nvidia

I'm setting up a conda environment to use pytorch 1.4.0 (on Ubuntu 20.04.2), but getting the error message:

> ValueError: Unknown CUDA arch (8.6) or GPU not supported

I know this has been asked before, but no answer fits my case. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66974215/9329400) answer suggests that the CUDA version is too old. However, I updated my CUDA version to the most recent, and get the same error message.

nvcc -V says I have CUDA 11 installed, and when I run nvidia-smi I get this info:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.84       Driver Version: 460.84       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

which, according to the [NVIDIA docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/), should work be compatible:

[image]

Another auxilliary question: What does the "8.6" in CUDA arch (8.6) represent?

Comment: *"pytorch 1.4.0"* Why?

Comment: 8.6 refers to specific members of the Ampere family of GPUs, such as any RTX 30xx card, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific versions of PyTorch work only with specific versions of CUDA.

If you are using CUDA-11.1, you'll need a fairly recent version of PyTorch. You need to either upgrade your PyTorch, or downgrade your CUDA.

Comment: Is there a way to know which CUDA version will be compatible with my pytorch version?

Comment: @JoshBone Look at the link I gave below.

Comment: @JoshBone Yes. pytorch.org lists them. Also see Ivan's link.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can grab PyTorch v1.4 for CUDA 10.0 from [here](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html):

```sh
pip install torch==1.4.0+cu100 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Comment: I have pytorch installed. This is not what I'm having trouble with.