# import torch OSError: [WinError 127]

Tags: installation, import, torch, oserror

I'm trying to install torch-gpu. I have installed cuda 11.1 and installed torch via the command `pip3 install torch==1.8.1+cu111 torchvision==0.9.1+cu111 torchaudio===0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

It is so stupid but during the importing I have the following error `OSError: [WinError 127] Error loading "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\lib\c10_cuda.dll" or one of its dependencies.`.

c10_cuda.dll exists in that directory, I spent several days and still can't solve it. I need torch-gpu and that's the point of using that possibility, please, do not comment 'install torch-cpu'.

Comment: Other users might also find this questions useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359175/pytorch-says-that-cuda-is-not-available

Answer (score 4):

*Answering the question myself*

To install torch-gpu one should:

1. check the latest (or not) versions and compatible cuda version: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/, at this moment it is 11.1.
2. download and install cuda of the established version in 1) step (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive). That depends on the gpu, if any problems you may download older versions or maybe you have it installed? then you can check version manually in the command line: `nvcc --version`.
3. install torch using commands as found in the 1) step (for instance `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge`)
4. check the installation success as `import torch torch.cuda.is_available()`.

In my case I had to delete previously installed torch `pip uninstall torch` and use `conda clean -a` for installation to end successfully.

Comment: I faced a similar problem and had to switch from installing with `pip` to `conda` as well...

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as I figured it might help someone else,
I experienced the same issue, and it turned out that I was importing a module before PyTorch (PySpin is the one I used), and it caused the same error you got.

Note - I use PIP and not Conda, on Windows.

This caused the missing DLL error, even though it existed.

```
import PySpin
import torch
```

this fixed the missing DLL error

```
import torch
import PySpin
```