# CUDA not available on RTX 3080, even though CUDA was used to build PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, anaconda, gpu, pytorch-lightning

In my conda enviroment created using [this yaml](https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion/blob/main/environment.yaml), I get "*RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available*" when trying to run stable diffusion.

I am running Windows 11 with an RTX 3080.

I have wiped all my conda envs and recreated them again, but the problem persists.

Here is the output of *collect_env*:

```
PyTorch version: 1.11.0
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 11.3
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
GCC version: Could not collect
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: version 3.22.5
Libc version: N/A

Python version: 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: 11.2.152
GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080
Nvidia driver version: 516.94
cuDNN version: Could not collect
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Is XNNPACK available: True

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.19.2
[pip3] pytorch-lightning==1.4.2
[pip3] torch==1.11.0
[pip3] torch-fidelity==0.3.0
[pip3] torchmetrics==0.6.0
[pip3] torchvision==0.12.0
[conda] blas                      1.0                         mkl
[conda] cudatoolkit               11.3.1               h59b6b97_2
[conda] mkl                       2021.4.0           haa95532_640
[conda] mkl-service               2.4.0            py38h2bbff1b_0
[conda] mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py38h277e83a_0
[conda] mkl_random                1.2.2            py38hf11a4ad_0
[conda] numpy                     1.19.2           py38ha4e8547_1
[conda] numpy-base                1.19.2           py38h5bb6eb2_1
[conda] pytorch                   1.11.0          py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8_0    pytorch
[conda] pytorch-lightning         1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
[conda] pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
[conda] torch-fidelity            0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchmetrics              0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchvision               0.12.0               py38_cu113    pytorch
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359175/pytorch-says-that-cuda-is-not-available

Comment: That user's problem was that their nvidia drivers were too old. I'm running 516.94, so that's not the case. Perhaps it's possible that my drivers are two recent for cuda 11.2.x, but I can't find any reference to that being a possibility, or what driver version I would need.