# EasyOCR used under Python / Torch Multiprocessing is defaulting to CPU

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, cpu, python-multiprocessing

I am using EasyOCR for text extraction from images. It uses PyTorch. There are multiple images in different folders and the sequence in which these folders are read isn't consequential.

When run in sequence, EasyOCR is by default using GPU and is faster compared to when run on CPU. But when Python / Torch Multiprocessing is invoked, so that the multiple folders are read in parallel, EasyOCR is defaulting to CPU.
`torch.cuda.is_available` returns `False`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If torch.cuda.is_available returns False,

1. Verify your device has a GPU.
2. Verify that the installed version of CUDA is supported on your GPU.
3. Verify that you have installed torch with CUDA support.

Check this question for additional details:
[Why `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns False even after installing pytorch with cuda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987997/why-torch-cuda-is-available-returns-false-even-after-installing-pytorch-with)