# Why doesn't torch see сuda?

Tags: pytorch, torch

i have problem with torch and cuda.

`torch.version.__version__` gives "1.5.1+cu101"

`torch.version.cuda` gives "10.1"

`torch.backends.cudnn.version()` gives "7603"

But `torch.cuda.is_avaliable()` gives False. What can be wrong?

Parameters of my system:

Linux-x86_64 (Ubuntu 20.04)

GeForce GTX 1050

NVIDIA Driver Version: 460.67

Comment: May you run the `$ nvcc --version` cmd and show the output?

Comment: nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why \`torch.cuda.is\_available()\` returns False even after installing pytorch with cuda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987997/why-torch-cuda-is-available-returns-false-even-after-installing-pytorch-with)

Comment: How did you install pytorch? Can you show the results of `nvidia-smi`?