# torch.cuda.is_available() returns False why?

Tags: pytorch

Has anyone encountered this?

> I tried updating drivers and reinstalling cuda

Cuda Version: `11.4`

GPU: `GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop(6gb)`

OS: `Windows 10 home`

torch.**version**: `1.9.0+cpu`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a PyTorch version compiled for CPU, you should install the appropriate version instead:

- Using `conda`:

  ```
  conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
  ```
- Using `pip`:

  ```
  python -m pip install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent over 6 hours trying to install this library due to internet problems, but still, again, thanks more <3

Comment: I am using this command `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 matplotlib scipy opencv -c pytorch` which seems to be similar since it also installs cuda toolkit, but the pytorch version installed is the cpu only version.

Answer (score 4):

For others who find this: `torch.cuda.is_available()` doesn't give any debugging information, but if you try to *use* CUDA anyway, you'll get a more informative error message:

```py
>>> import torch
>>> torch.zeros(1).cuda()
```

Another answer with much more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61034368/69707

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different CUDA version than the offered in the command selection tool to install Pytorch, I recommend you to install the nightly binaries:

[image]

This worked for me having the cuda version 11.6:

```
pip install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu114
```