# GPU Pytorch with CUDA10.2 and GPU Pytorch with CUDA11.1

Tags: pytorch, anaconda, nvidia

I have been trying to test the installation of  the GPU-enabled `Pytorch` on Windows using `Anaconda`, and had the following observations:

Whether the version is `Stable (1.9.1)` or `LTS(1.8.2)`,(`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch` )I have to choose `CUDA 10.2` and the test of CUDA will pass

```
Import torch
Torch.cuda.is_available()
True
```

if I choose `CUDA11.1`, the installation will fail to pass the following test

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

Here is the system information for the reference; I am not clear why I cannot use CUDA11.1 in the Pytorch installation, and what are the criteria to choose it?

[image]

[image]

Here is the command I used to install `Pytorch` with `CUDA11.1`

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
```

Here is the information I run the env collection script:

```
Collecting environment information...
PyTorch version: 1.9.0+cpu
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: Could not collect
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
GCC version: (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: version 3.20.2
Libc version: N/A

Python version: 3.8.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep 29 2021, 19:15:57) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: 11.2.67
GPU models and configuration: Could not collect
Nvidia driver version: Could not collect
cuDNN version: Could not collect
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] botorch==0.5.0
[pip3] gpytorch==1.5.0
[pip3] numpy==1.20.3
[pip3] torch==1.9.0
[pip3] torchaudio==0.9.1
[pip3] torchvision==0.10.1
[conda] blas                      2.111                       mkl    conda-forge
[conda] blas-devel                3.9.0              11_win64_mkl    conda-forge
[conda] cudatoolkit               11.1.1               heb2d755_9    conda-forge
[conda] libblas                   3.9.0              11_win64_mkl    conda-forge
[conda] libcblas                  3.9.0              11_win64_mkl    conda-forge
[conda] liblapack                 3.9.0              11_win64_mkl    conda-forge
[conda] liblapacke                3.9.0              11_win64_mkl    conda-forge
[conda] mkl                       2021.3.0           hb70f87d_564    conda-forge
[conda] mkl-devel                 2021.3.0           h57928b3_565    conda-forge
[conda] mkl-include               2021.3.0           hb70f87d_564    conda-forge
[conda] numpy                     1.21.2           py38h089cfbf_0    conda-forge
[conda] pytorch                   1.9.1           py3.8_cuda11.1_cudnn8_0    pytorch
[conda] torchaudio                0.9.1                      py38    pytorch
[conda] torchvision               0.10.1               py38_cu111    pytorch
```

Comment: How exactly did you install torch with conda? Here (https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) it says if you like to install it with CUDA 11.1 adding `-c conda-forge` as channel is required. Hence you should use: `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge`

Comment: Assuming you used the command provided by Tinu to install pytorch then I don't see a good reason it's not working from the system information you provided. Your hardware and drivers should support cuda 11.1. My guess would be something conda related. If you haven't already, you may want to try installing again from a new conda environment. If that still doesn't work then it would be helpful if you post the output of the [collect_env script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/pytorch/master/torch/utils/collect_env.py) after installing pytorch with cuda 11.1.

Comment: @Tinu, I installed with -c conda-forge as Pytorch install guide suggests   Thanks.

Comment: @jodag, thanks for your reply, I will give it a second try, and run the script that you provided, thanks.

Comment: @jodag, I have updated the result of running collect env script. Thanks.

Comment: It seems something is going wrong in conda since it has installed pytorch 1.9.0 without cuda support via pip despite installing the pytorch 1.9.1 cuda 11.1 conda package. I don't know enough about how the conda installation works but this is not normal. In weird cases like this I tend to start over with a new conda environment.