# Pytorch installs fine but cannot find my GPU

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, anaconda, conda

There are loads of questions on here about this & I have read those that I can find. Still `pytorch` ignores my GPU.

I have a Win10 64x machine with a NVIDIA Maxwell GeForce GTX 960 with a compute ability of 5.2 so well within CUDA 11.x territory. I updated my drivers prior to `pytorch` installation.

I went over to the [Pytorch - get started page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) selected the appropriate combination & copied the `conda` command for that set up. In my case this was,

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.6 -c pytorch -c conda-forge`

I go to my `conda` command terminal & open up my environment that I use for things like OpenCV and enter the command. Everything installs, no errors.

I then check the installation by opening Python & entering the following,

```
>>>import torch
>>>print(torch.__version__)

1.12.1

>>>print(torch.cuda.is_available())

False
```

So what am I missing here?

Comment: What version of Python do you have? Apparently `pytorch` only supports Python v3.7-3.9 on Windows. Perhaps your Python version is outside that range?

Comment: @tdpu python 3.8.11

Comment: That's strange. 

Looking at the [CUDA compatibility chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported), it looks like CUDA Toolkit v11.6 covers CUDA compute support for Maxwell versions 3.5 - 8.7.

I'm wondering if somehow the Nvidia/CUDA drivers are busted - you could try reinstalling or rolling back. See also: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.6.0/maxwell-compatibility-guide/index.html.

There's a lot of suggestions (with better explanation) in this [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61034368/13752965), you might find some help there.