# General question regarding pytorch and cuda

Tags: bash, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-lightning

I recently started working on pytorch and cuda (+conda environments).

My working environment is basically a computer clusters where I submit a job via `sbatch run_gpu.sbatch` file and the computing center will send me back outputs.

The system (main computer) has all the packages and modules like conda, python, cuda, etc. Inside the `home/my-user-name` directory of it, I have created a conda environment and downloaded `pytorch-1.11.0-py3.8_cuda11.5_cudnn8.3.2_0`.

To make sure, I loaded Cuda/11.5 (this is in the main computer, not my directory) via `.bashrc` file.

**Is it normal for `print(torch.cuda.is_available())` to print `False` when I do**

```py
python;
  import torch
  print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

**in my conda environment because I haven't submitted a job to que so that it cannot find GPU units in my computer?**

Still,

```py
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
print(torch.version.cuda)
```

gives me results of `1.11.0` and `11.5` as desired.

So I was curious why pytorch and cuda are installed well as desired, but does not seem to be connected to the loaded `Cuda/11.5` from the `.bashrc` file.

If so could you let me know if there is any way to check the connectivity?

Or will this problem be solved once I submit a job to a main computer which has GPU units?

Thank you!

Comment: `torch.cuda.is_available()` will check for actual physical device with suitable driver. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987997/why-torch-cuda-is-available-returns-false-even-after-installing-pytorch-with