# How does the pytorch CUDA version and CUDA actually works?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Here is my conda environment's package list:

[image: MY PACKAGE LIST]

As you can see, I have not installed cudatoolkit and the nvcc comand is not usable. But I do have installed pytorch in CUDA version.

However, when I import torch in python and check `torch.cuda.is_available()`, it returns Ture.

I even run this test script:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import Module
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import LambdaLR


class TestNet(Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(10,10)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)
    

if __name__=="__main__":
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = "cuda"
    else:
        device = "cpu"
    print(f"Using device {device}")
    test_samples = torch.rand([32,10]).to(device)
    gt_matrix = torch.eye(10).to(device)
    target = torch.matmul(test_samples, gt_matrix)

    model = TestNet().to(device)

    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1)
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    scheduler = LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=lambda x: min(x, 24)/24)

    for epoch in range(128):
        logits = model(test_samples)
        loss = criterion(logits, target)
        learning_rate = optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"]

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

        print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{24}, loss {loss.item()}, lr {learning_rate}")
    
    print("Learned matrix:")
    print(model.state_dict()["linear.weight"])
```

And it runs successfully.

So I am curious about how pytorch CUDA version actually works? Does it need a pre-installed CUDA toolkit or not? Besides, what is the difference between installing CUDA by `conda install cudatoolkit` , `conda install cuda` and even installing by graphical installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987997/why-torch-cuda-is-available-returns-false-even-after-installing-pytorch-with/61034368#61034368) and this [forum thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-finds-cuda-despite-nvcc-not-found/166754), you are not required to have `nvcc` installed on your local machine since PyTorch is shipped with its own CUDA library. The only requirement is that you have a CUDA driver installed on your device and it supports the CUDA version you installed via Pytorch.

I would assume that `conda install cudatoolkit` installs a standalone CUDA toolkit, but is independent of PyTorch. Following the [installation page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/), you should instead use `conda install pytorch::pytorch-cuda`. That way you install PyTorch with CUDA support.

Comment: Thanks, this really explained what I saw.